# Vscode Shortcut for run script on terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is a way that allows me that when I am editing a js file I can through a shortcut: open the terminal and run it automatically:

1- Open terminal
2- node my-file.js

Right now it only manages to open terminal with shortcut "ctrl + ´" but then I have to type "node my-file.js"

Answer (score 1):

There is easy way to run JavaScript, no configuration needed:

1. Install the [Code Runner Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)
2. Open the JavaScript code file in vscode, then use shortcut `Control+Alt+N` (or `⌃ Control+ Option+N` on macOS), or press `F1` and then `select/type Run Code`, the code will run and the output will be shown in the Output Window.