# Run simple VSC playground macros with keystroke

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSC for JavaScript. Question: surely there's an easy way to run a "Hello World" macro from editor with a single keystroke? Currently I have to:

1. Toggle to console with custom keyboard shortcut
2. Enter filename (e.g. "HelloWorld.js" or up arrow)
3. "Enter" key to run
4. Toggle back to editor with custom keyboard shortcut

Learning JavaScript/NodeJS, coding background is Excel VBA (long story...). I'm used to VBA Macro Editor where you do all above by hitting F5 [VBA Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngYuD.png) (or step through with F8). Code runs on spreadsheet or 'Immediate Window' below - see photo. Can do similar on online editors like Repl.it with "Run" button [Repl.it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBiIZ.png).

How do you do this in VSC?

Comment: Similar question: [Vscode Shortcut for run script on terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64264923/vscode-shortcut-for-run-script-on-terminal)

Comment: [Node.js debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to your problem is using an extension called [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).
I have used this for C++ in VSC and works equally well in literally every programming language.It gives you your console output in the terminal itself ([As in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkyBx.png))
Funnily enough I,also use <kbd>F5</kbd> for running code and you can do the same by-

- Typing <kbd>F1</kbd> and typing `Run code` and changing its settings  [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehjbY.png) and you are done